# Arraylist without remove object

Tags: java

I have an `Arraylist`, for example

```
ArrayList<SomeType> newObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to use an object from the `Arraylist` without using the method `remove`.
I don't want to remove the object from the list, just to refer to it and use its methods.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: So do so; what's the specific issue?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what your issue/question is.

Comment: I think OP wants to get a reference to an object from the list and when he sets that reference to null, the object must still be in the list. Or at least this is what I got from his explanation

Comment: when looking for desired functionality the public API documentation could be a useful resource... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 5):

Use the method `newObjectList.get(index)` instead

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int))

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the `remove` method using the Collections.unmodifiableList() construct:

```
List<Object> newObjectList = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<Object>());
```

This will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` when trying to add or remove an object.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking to *restrict* removal, rather to reference a list item *without removing it*.

Comment: I don't *know* OP is asking for :) I.e. just referencing it without removing it - it's so simple, that nobody should ask that on SO. Thus I made a guess, like this *might* be relevant too.